# Scrapy: Scheduled crawl with sqlite logic

Tags: python, sqlite, scrapy, logic, schedule

I'm trying to build a scraper that will check for changes every 1h, save details of new items to sqlite lib and if found new item- send email.
I'm rather a beginner discovering scrapy.

I have a working spider with itemloader and I receive a dictionaries with details of each item. All items are located on one page. There's around 20-30 elems, but the max change every our goes up to 5 items. I need help in desinging a logic for this. So far I was thinking: connect, do a for loop range(5) and check if item['id'] is in db. If yes- next. If not- compose email.
Is that a good approach for checking for a change? Please advice on the logic

Comment: simply addressing your approach, that's not the best way to do it, you want to supply all the `ids` at once and perform a lookup in the db to return the results at once as opposed to make 5 subsequent db calls

Comment: What do you have so far?